# unable to select or access uitableview cell that is out of scroll bounds (cells that are not visible)

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am selecting cells programatically using:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:1];
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

UITableViewCell *anotherCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[anotherCell setSelected:YES];
anotherCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

This works great for all the other cells in the uitableview, but for the couple that are past the bounds of the view, when I scroll down, I see that the cells do not have checkmarks on them.

How can I put checkmarks/ select cells that are past the scrollbounds?

Comment: Instead of using this can you save this selected indexPath in an array or so and in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` use this info to show the checkmark. It's always easier to change the dataSource binding to the view and then reload the view.

Comment: Remember that cells that are not visible usually do not exist and are created as needed.  Therefore you can't (and shouldn't) use your views to store data. That is what your model is for.  Save the state of the checkmarks in your model or a local property and set itbin cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: thx! im indeed not storing the data in the cells, but i need to preserve the state of the table when it is loaded again. when the table's loaded, where should I progromatically select the cells?

Comment: You should set the selected state either in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` or `willDisplayCellAtIndexPath:` so that it is set before it is displayed.  If you need to change the value for a cell that is not displayed, you just update your data source and it will read it when the cell is about to be displayed.  The only time that you need to worry about updating a cell is if you need to change the state of a cell that is being displayed, and even then you typically only reload the cells for the appropriate row(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"genericCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:22.0];


    //set selected based on indexPath.row and indexPath.section
    [cell setSelected:YES];


    //or
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;



}
```